# post form multidimensional array in coldfusion

Tags: html, forms, post, coldfusion

I am trying to post the following :

`<input name="answer[1][]" value="Answer 1 question 1"/>`
`<input name="answer[1][]" value="Answer 2 question 1"/>`

`<input name="answer[2][]" value="Answer 1 question 2"/>`
`<input name="answer[2][]" value="Answer 2 question 2"/>`

Unfortunately I receive a coldfusion error when posting:

Expression-Element ANSWER is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can't just call a form field "answers[1][]" and hope that some how ColdFusion will work out that string - because that's all "answers[1][]" is: a string - is supposed to be interpreted as  an array reference.  CF doesn't work like that.

Even if it *did* work like that, you'd need to put a value in the second dimension of the array notation: `answers[1][]` is not valid CFML.

The first troubleshooting step when variables are appearing to be different to what you expect is to dump the variable out (or in this case, the `form` scope out):

```
<cfdump var="#form#">
```

This would quickly reveal that you don't have an array, you have a two variables in the form scope: one called `answer[1][]` and the other `answer[2][]` (where each variable is literally called that).  Dot-notation rules in CF won't allow this to be referenced as `form.answer[1][]`, you need to reference it as `form["answer[1][]"]`.

As of ColdFusion 10, one can have form variables with the same name being set in the form scope as an array, by setting this in your Application.cfc:

```
 this.sameformfieldsasarray = true
```

However that obviously (?) only works for a single dimension array.

If you want a multi-dimension array, you'll have to DIY with a loop over the form scope and a variable-name check to see which array / dimension each value should go in.

Comment: +1 `this.sameformfieldsasarray = true` i didn't know this, thanks :-)

Comment: Appending a single [] to a field's name is a valid way *in some languages* of identically named fields producing a (single-dimension) array, instead of a comma-delimited list. Railo has supported this since at least v2 (possibly earlier), for both Url and Form fields. Is a shame Adobe added a Form-only switch instead of using the same/existing syntax.

Answer (score 1):

What's probably happening is that ColdFusion is trying to create the FORM Scope using the key "answer[1][]" and evaluating it as an expression which is invalid variable name for ColdFusion/Java. Depending on what you want to do, you'll probably have to rename your input fields to something like answer_Q_A aka answer_1_1, answer_1_2, answer_2_1 and then process into an array from there.

```
<cfset answerArray = arrayNew(2)>

<cfloop collection="#form#" item="thisField">
     <cfif left(thisField,6) eq 'ANSWER' and listLen(thisField,'_') eq 3>
         <cfset answerArray[listGetAt(thisField,2,'_')][listGetAt(thisField,3,'_')] = form[thisField]>
     </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Adam and Ben for your answers, they have been very helpful and drove me to the solution of the puzzle.
I have been coding often in php where using name="xxx[]" creates an array in the $_POST variable.
Now Coldfusion throws an error because there is no need of adding the "[]".

What i did is: 
`<input name="answer_1" value="Answer 1 question 1"/>`
`<input name="answer_1" value="Answer 2 question 1"/>`

`<input name="answer_2" value="Answer 1 question 2"/>`
`<input name="answer_2" value="Answer 2 question 2"/>`

Coldfusion will return 2 structures "answer_1" and "answer_2" containing 2 comma separated strings.

But if my string would contain commas eg: Answer 1, question 1

This would give me problems when I will try to transform the string in a list.

Using the method getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap() Codfusion transforms the comma separated strings in arrays:

Struct answer_1 would contain an array:

array[1]="Answer 1 question 1"
array[2]="Answer 1 question 2"

And this is exactly what i needed !